# Readfile API not reading anything while reading we are getting buffer as empty

Tags: c++, pipe, readfile, handle, createprocess

Here is some details

[image]

****Note:-** All command are working fine with OSCALL function in  compiler VC12**

with complier VC14

exe name is RemDicomNodes.exe

**CMD command prompt**:-

RemDicomNodes 5 6 1 2 3 10 8 9

RemDicomNodes.exe 1 A

RemDicomNodes 2 B B 0 localhost 1 "BE" 104 3 1 7 7 60 0 "" 2 0 0 0 0 "" 3 0 0 0 0 ""  0 6 1 2 3 10 8 9  0 0 0 0 NoConversion 0 0  0  0  1 0 0 1 BE 0 0 0 IPv4 0 0 10 0 1 0

Above all commands are working fine and showing proper output on CMD command prompt

**With OSCAll function**:-

RemDicomNodes 5 6 1 2 3 10 8 9

#(Working fine i am getting output in variable "outputbuffer" which i am using inside readfile API)

RemDicomNodes.exe 1 A

#(Working fine i am getting output in variable "outputbuffer" which i am using inside readfile API)

RemDicomNodes.exe 2 B B 0 localhost 1 """BE"""" " 104 3 1 7 7 60 0 " """""" " 2 0 0 0 0 " """""" " 3 0 0 0 0 " """""""  0 6 1 2 3 10 8 9  0 0 0 0 NoConversion 0 0  0  0  1 0 0 0 AE 0 0 0 IPv4 0 0 10 0 1 0"

**#Problem**(that any arguments we are send but it is not working, i am not getting output in variable "outputbuffer" which i am using inside readfile API it is not printing anything )

This is the function which i am using to run my exe

```
BOOL MagicWatchComProc::OSCall(CString i_cmd, CString& a_output, DWORD& a_exitCode, long i_timeOut)

{
    STARTUPINFO      aStartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION aProcessInfo;
    HANDLE               hReadHandle    = NULL;
    HANDLE               hWriteHandle   = NULL;
    HANDLE               hErrorHandle   = NULL;
    DWORD                dwBytesRead    = 0;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa             = {sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE};
    //time_t l_timeOut = 300000; //5 min.
    
    //reset output string
    a_output = "";
    
    DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: launching ") + i_cmd);

    if (!i_cmd)
    {
        DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: Error: empty command\n"));
        return false;
    }
    
    //reset errors
    SetLastError(0);
    
    // Initialize process startup structure
    FillMemory(&aStartupInfo, sizeof(aStartupInfo), 0);
    //GetStartupInfo(&aStartupInfo);
    aStartupInfo.cb       = sizeof(aStartupInfo);
    aStartupInfo.dwFlags      = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    aStartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    
    // Create pipe that will transfer the process output to our buffer
    if(!CreatePipe(&hReadHandle, &hWriteHandle, &sa, 0))
    {
        DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: Error: Pipe creation\n"));
        return false;
    }
    // Set process' stdout to our pipe
    aStartupInfo.hStdOutput = hWriteHandle;
    
    // We are going to duplicate our pipe's write handle
    // and pass it as stderr to create process.  The idea
    // is that some processes have been known to close
    // stderr which would also close stdout if we passed
    // the same handle.  Therefore we make a copy of stdout's
    // pipe handle.
    
    if (!DuplicateHandle( GetCurrentProcess(), hWriteHandle, GetCurrentProcess(), &hErrorHandle, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS ))
    {
        CloseHandle(hReadHandle);
        CloseHandle(hWriteHandle);
        DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: Error: duplicate handle\n"));
        return false;
    }
    aStartupInfo.hStdError = hErrorHandle;
    
    // Check input parameter
    TCHAR l_inputCommand[2048];
    
    _tcscpy(l_inputCommand, i_cmd);
    
    // Create process of service program
    if(!CreateProcess( NULL, l_inputCommand, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &aStartupInfo, &aProcessInfo ))
    {
        CloseHandle(hReadHandle);
        CloseHandle(hWriteHandle);
        CloseHandle(hErrorHandle);
        DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: Error: could not create process\n"));
        return false;
    }
    
    // The process is alive now and has inherited the environment, now
    // we can release the critical section
    
    // Close the write end of our pipe (both copies)
    // so it will die when the child process terminates
    CloseHandle(hWriteHandle);
    CloseHandle(hErrorHandle);
    
    // We close the handle of the process in order to prevent memory leaks when
    // the process terminates.
    //CloseHandle(aProcessInfo.hThread);
    
    // Allocate memory for output buffer
    DWORD   dwAvailableOutput = 16;
    CHAR    outputbuffer[18];
    
    //CString strPipeName;
    //DWORD dwSize = 0;
    
    //GetNamedPipeHandleState( hReadHandle, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, strPipeName.GetBuffer(1), dwSize );
    //WaitNamedPipe( strPipeName, 100 );
    
    // -> Read output from CGI program
    time_t l_time;
    time_t l_startTime;
    time(&l_startTime);
    do
    {
        time(&l_time);
    
        if( (l_time - l_startTime) > i_timeOut)
            {
                SetLastError(WAIT_TIMEOUT);
                break;
            }
        
        if( ReadFile( hReadHandle, outputbuffer, dwAvailableOutput, &dwBytesRead, NULL ) )
        {
            outputbuffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;  // null terminate
            a_output += outputbuffer;
        }
    }
    //We are done
    while ( GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE );
    
    //reset ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE error
    if(GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
        SetLastError(0);
    
    //DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: command output: ") + a_output);
    
    //CloseHandle(hErrorHandle);
    CloseHandle(hReadHandle);
    
    if( !GetLastError() )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_TRACE(_T("OSCall: Error: cmd command failed. Error code: ")+ i2cs(GetLastError()) +_T("; ExitCode: ")+ i2cs(a_exitCode) +_T("."));
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    DWORD   dwExitCode = 0;
    long l_timeOut = 60000; //ms = 10 min
    BOOL    bRet    = FALSE;
    CString strInstallLmutil(_T("cmd.exe /C "));
    CString strLmutilInstallFile(_T("remdicomnodes.exe"));
    CString strPathLmutilInstall;
    strPathLmutilInstall.Format(_T("%s\\bin\\%s"),strtemp,strLmutilInstallFile);    
    strInstallOption = _T("");
    strInstallOption = _T(" 2 B B 0 localhost 1 \"""BE""\"" " 104 3 1 7 7 60 0 " "\"""\"" " 2 0 0 0 0 " "\"""\"" " 3 0 0 0 0 " "\"""\"""  0 6 1 2 3 10 8 9  0 0 0 0 NoConversion 0 0  0  0  1 0 0 0 AE 0 0 0 IPv4 0 0 10 0 1 0");
    bRet = OSCall ( cmd, l_commandOutput, dwExitCode, l_timeOut);
    SAM_TRACE1("OSCall: bRet value: :%d ",bRet);
    if( bRet == FALSE )
    {
        SAM_TRACE0("remdicomnodes.exe execution failed \n");
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Please advise me

Comment: @Remy Lebeau using CreateFileW function i can read the buffer using Readfile API

Comment: can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong in this code ?